# Hostname lookup (ping) hangs indefinitely

Tags: centos, dns, ping

Normally if I try pinging an address it will either do so promptly or state that the host is unknown. On one machine however, it seems that trying to ping an unknown host will cause it to hang forever (greater than 15 minutes).

This seems to causing problem in the boot process, hanging when trying to start sendmail services and so on.

Booting in single user mode, the only time ping responds is when pinging one of the hosts listed in `/etc/hosts`. Otherwise it will hang.

On the other hand, `nslookup` does seem to timeout after approx. 15 seconds.

ETA This seems to only happen in Single user mode. Once booted up normally (although had to disable SMB and sendmail services to do so) ping now times out if given an invalid name (like 'cabbage')

The 'host' command seems to return the following regardless if given a valid hostname or not;

```
(hostname).(domain name) mail is handled by 5 smtp01.(company domain name).
(hostname).(domain name) mail is handled by 9 cinsmtp01.(company domain name).
(hostname).(domain name) mail is handled by 9 alpsmtp01.(company domain name).
```

IIRC it was doing this in both the single boot mode and when booted normally and wasn't hanging. I'll confirm if I get a chance to reboot the machine again.

This is the only CentOS box on our local network - all others are Windows machines so can't really compare against a working machine. But below is a result of grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf

```
#hosts:     db files nisplus nis dns
hosts:      db files wins nisplus nis dns
```

The resolv.conf has a number of nameserver entries in it, some of which may not be valid anymore, I'll investigate further and report back.

Comment: For an example target host name of `cabbage`, what does `host cabbage` return in your situation? Does it return or hang? Please also add output of `grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` to your question. And identify to us whether these match similar results from a working server.